# Android Map Application - Performance

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on an application wherein I show office locations on Google map. The basic functionality is working fine. However, when user moves to another area on the map, the tiles take some time to load. What are ways or best practices to make the tile-loading smoother and quicker?

Answer (score 0):

This is all handled by the google maps API.  There's no simple way to make tiles load quicker, unless your users use the new "download maps for offline use" function.

The only other thing I could think of is to spoof the user's actions to fool the API into thinking the user is looking at a different location, allowing you to preload some locations.

Hope this helps!